# Clamping electrical outlet to concrete wall without drilling?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

This is what my receptacle looks like.

[image]

The outlet works fine, but it's sticking out since the outlet can't clamp to anything.

The wall is solid concrete and it's an apartment, so I prefer not drilling. Besides, I don't have a hammer drill. The mounting screws don't have anything to hold on to since that rusted out long ago.

I was thinking of buying one of these [electrical outlet boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz1e1.png), but the I don't where the screws in the corners would go.

I don't want to remove the outlet unless I plan to fix it, but think of it this way: the concrete wall has a big hole for the outlet, and the cables are sticking out from the back of that hole.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Solid concrete can be drilled, with the right bit and perhaps a hammer drill, though that might not be the best approach for this problem.

Comment: I don't understand. Is there no flange on the box? Please provide a better photo of the situation.

Comment: And if it's an apartment this is a clear code violation that the owner should resolve.

Comment: Removing the faceplate (by removing the center screw) will let you get a better photo of what we're actually dealing with. In this pic I can't tell whether the problem is that the ears the switch bolts to are missing, buried in concrete, or if someone just failed to install one of those bolts.

Comment: Th outlet you pictured is for drywall I believe.

Comment: A better photo would be great, I'm a bit concerned that the "mounting screws don't have anything to hold on to because that _rusted_ out long ago." Rust indicates the presence of water, which doesn't sound great in this situation.

Comment: Take off the cover plate (one screw) and show us what's behind it.

Comment: It's not water. We're near the ocean and everything has rust.

Answer (score 4):

Two answers in one:

##### If you own the home:

> *The wall is solid concrete, so I can't drill*

That is a false premise. You can't drill with a regular drill. You can generally drill concrete pretty easily with a *hammer drill*.

Open up the box so we can see what you've got. It may be possible to retrofit a box to fit "just right" and attach properly. Or, provided there are a few inches to spare of wire/cable, you may be able to mount a metal box on the surface of the concrete. That will look "industrial" but is perfectly normal in basements, workshops, garages, etc.

##### If you rent the home:

**Call your landlord.** You can't do electrical work without permission of the landlord. In most places you also need to be a licensed electrician to work in a multi-unit building.

You *might* get away with a very simple switch or receptacle replacement, but you already know this isn't simple. Beyond slapping glue or tape on this to hold it in place (which I don't recommend), you need landlord/electrician to do the job.

Comment: I've edited the question. I prefer not drilling. I also don't have a hammer drill.

Comment: But this is a great excuse to buy a hammer drill :-)

Comment: Can rent them also, but being in an apartment should not have to, since it should be under apartment maintenance.

Comment: **You don't need a hammer drill.  Just a masonry bit and a regular drill.**

Answer (score 4):

### Junction boxes *are required*

You can't have a receptacle flopping around in the wall without an enclosure to shield the wires.  I know that requirement seems a little dumb when the void behind it is pure concrete, but think about wood frame construction. You don't want an arcing fault on the outlet's connections able to directly set wood on fire.

You still need a junction box. And given that the void is of limited size, you probably want the smallest box available.  That would be a steel "Handy-Box" like a Raco 650 or 660.  Use cable clamps such as Halex 20511 to bring Romex into the box.

As far as physically mounting it in the space, I would probably get a piece of "1-by" wood and trim it so it can fit in the space behind the box (and bring the box up flush).  This might involve chiseling away some brick/concrete.   I would attach the wood to the concrete using epoxy, with lots of fairing filler added to it to make it more like peanut butter, and then brace it in there while it sets up.  Give it overnight to cure, then you can use 3/4" wood screws to mount the steel box to the wood.

Answer (score 2):

The linked box is a rework box.  The screws spin the toggle or arm that tightens to your wall board.  If you wall is concrete then there is no hollow backing for this to tighten against.

You can drill concrete with a hammer drill and a masonry bit.

A picture showing the rusted pieces might allow more solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential solution would be to use this style of metal mounting ears.  I think there is a generic name for it, but it doesn't seem to used in listings.
Here is the RACO product at Lowes.
https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-2-Pack-Gray-Metal-New-Work-Old-Work-Interior-Wall-Electrical-Box-Mounting-Brackets/3126789

You slip the brackets on each side of the box and engage the back of the wall, then bend the brackets into the box.  This requires a box with some plaster ears to hold it out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might be a matter of the indicated screw, which attaches the outlet to the box, is missing or not tightened enough to put the outlet flush into the box.

If that's the case it isn't something that would require an electrician to fix, but since you're renting the apartment, that's clearly a job for the landlord or maintenance staff to take care of. You pay rent, that's not your responsibility.

A homeowner could cut power to that outlet and install or tighten up the screw indicated in the picture.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the threaded hole for that screw got rusted and literally disintegrated. So that screw doesn't have anything to hold on to.

Comment: Bummer. Call the landlord to hire an electrician. By law you aren't allowed to do the work necessary to repair this in an apartment building.